# Angular 12, RxJS: safe to use takeWhile without onDestroy?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a general confusion with `takeWhile`.

What I want to achieve:

- Wait for `fireAuthUser$` Observable to have a value
- once that happens, do some stuff
- if `fireAuthUser$` Observable does not receive a value, cancel once the component is left

```js
export class AuthService implements OnDestroy {
    fireAuthUser: BehaviorSubject<firebase.User | undefined> = new BehaviorSubject<firebase.User | undefined>(undefined);
    public readonly fireAuthUser$: Observable<firebase.User | undefined> = this.fireAuthUser.asObservable();
    private subscription?: Subscription;

    constructor(public fire: AngularFireAuth) {
        this.subscription = this.fire.authState.subscribe((fireAuthUser) => {
            if (fireAuthUser) {
                this.fireAuthUser.next(fireAuthUser);
                // ...
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscription?.unsubscribe();
    }

    doSomeStuff(): void {
       //do some stuff
    }

}
```

```js
export class Foo implements OnInit {

    constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
         this.auth.fireAuthUser$.pipe(takeWhile((fireAuthUser) => fireAuthUser === undefined)).subscribe({
          complete: () => this.auth.doSomeStuff()
        });
    }

}
```

The code above works. However, according to [Angular/RxJS When should I unsubscribe from `Subscription`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription/41177163?#comment77901337_42695571) by using takeWhile, the observable execution will not be cancelled on `ngDestroy` of the component. So from my understanding, I need to manually set a `.next` value in my `ngOnDestroy`, otherwise my `takeWhile` would never cancel? Use case would be, i.e., if the user cannot login (no `fireAuthUser` exists)

However, I guess I cannot simply put a `ngOnDestroy(): void { this.auth.fireAuthUser.next(undefined); }` as this would always erase my `fireAuthUser`, which is a problem if the user does have a `fireAuthUser` object? So what should I do in this case? Or did I misunderstand this remark and my code is safe to use?

Comment: why can't you just implement `OnDestroy` save the subscription and unsubscribe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [takeUntil](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil) Operator. It will listen to `this.auth.fireAuthUser$` untill current component is destroyed

```
import { Subject, takeUntil } from 'rxjs';

export class Foo implements OnInit{
  private destroy$ = new Subject();
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.auth.fireAuthUser$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe({
        next: (data) => console.log(data),
        complete: () => this.uponComplete(),
      });
  }

  uponComplete() {
    console.log('Finally completed');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

See demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hh91ww?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (click on `Go to Auth` timer will start and click on `Home` it will unsubscribe)

Answer (score 0):

Use `takeUntil` operator.
I love to create a `BaseComponent` that extend the class that have observable.

```
@Component({
    template: ''
})
export abstract class BaseComponent implements OnDestroy {
    protected unsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject();

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy();
    }

    private destroy(): void {
        this.unsubscribe.next();
        this.unsubscribe.complete();
    }
}
```

after this class, you can extend all the class you want, and use `takeUntil` method for destroying observable when the component is destroyed.

```
export class LeadEditComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit(): void {
         this.subscription = this.fire.authState
            .pipe(
                 takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
             )
            .subscribe((fireAuthUser) => {
                if (fireAuthUser) {
                    this.fireAuthUser.next(fireAuthUser);
                    // ...
                }
         });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just use `ngOnDestroy` to unsubscribe?

```
export class Foo implements OnInit {

    private sub: Subscription;
    constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
         this.sub = this.auth.fireAuthUser$.pipe(takeWhile((fireAuthUser) => fireAuthUser === undefined)).subscribe({
          complete: () => this.auth.doSomeStuff()
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
      this.sub.unsubscribe()
    }

}
```